# How can I get a smartsheet as excel file and put it to cloudinary in PHP?

Tags: php, cloudinary, smartsheet-api

I need your help to get a smartsheet as excel and put it to cloudinary in PHP.
I use the code bellow.

```
/**
 * @param $sheetId
 */
public function getSheetAsExcel($sheetId)
{
    $url = self::SMART_SHEET_BASE_URL . '/sheets/' . $sheetId;
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->smartsheetCredentials;
    $headers[] = 'Accept: application/vnd.ms-excel';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

A file is created in cloudinary but when I donwload it, I have a wrong format.

[screenshot of the message shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNnyM.png)

```
$outStream = $this->smartsheetClient->getSheetAsExcel($smart_sheet_id);
$file_name = 'filename.xlsx';
$cloudinarySignature = (new CloudinayClient())->getCloudinarySignature();

$temp = tmpfile();
$path = stream_get_meta_data($temp)['uri'];
fwrite($temp, file_put_contents($path, $outStream));
fseek($temp, 0);

$cloudinaryResponse = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($path, [
    "public_id" =>  $file_name,
    "resource_type" => "auto",
    "signature" => $cloudinarySignature,
    "version" => time()
]);

fclose($temp);
```

Comment: In your code, you are writing the Excel sheet's content to a local path on your file system before uploading it to Cloudinary. If you try to open the local file itself (without going through Cloudinary) does that work?

Comment: I'm coming back towards you. I test that and I tell you after.

Comment: I updated my code following your suggest and all are going correctly. The problem was probably the tmpfile().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my code with following. The problem was probably the tmpfile().

```
$file = $this->smartsheetClient->getSheetAsExcel($smart_sheet_id);
$file_name = 'filename.xlsx';
$cloudinarySignature = (new CloudinayClient())->getCloudinarySignature();

$path = self::TMP_FOLDER ."/$file_name";
file_put_contents($path, $file);

$cloudinaryResponse = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($path, [
    "public_id" =>  $file_name,
    "resource_type" => "auto",
    "signature" => $cloudinarySignature,
    "version" => time()
]);

unlink($path);
```